# How would I prove the following equivalence using logical identities?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

(X ⇒ Y ) ∨ (X ⇒ Z) ≡ (X ⇒ (Y ∨ Z))

The left hand side looks like two conditional identities and the right hand side also looks like some form of conditional identity. However, I can't seem to figure out how to prove the sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $p \Rightarrow q = \neg p \lor q$.

So $$LHS = (\neg X \lor Y) \lor (\neg X \lor Y) = \neg X \lor (Y \lor Z) = X \Rightarrow (Y\lor Z).$$

Answer (score 1):

The  left side is false only when both $X$ is true and $Y$ is false and also $X$ is true and $Z$ Is false.  That's precisely the only time the right side is false.  So the two sides are logically equivalent

Comment: My understanding of the intent of the question was to ask how to prove it *by using* logical identities a la GAVD's answer. With this understanding, your answer isn't an answer to the question asked.